# How to calculate the maximal GeoDistance and TravelDistance in a geo-region

Tags: geodesy, geographics

This is current method to find the maximal `EuclideanDistance` in American

```
NMaximize[
 EuclideanDistance[x, y], 
 {x ∈ BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[CountryData["UnitedStates", "Polygon"]],
  y ∈ BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[CountryData["UnitedStates", "Polygon"]]}
]
```

> `{57.8918, {x -> {-124.732, 48.381}, y -> {-66.9498, 44.8179}}}`

But as we know, `EuclideanDistance` is not suitable to calculate the geodesic distance. So I change it.

#### Failure one

```
NMinimize[
 QuantityMagnitude[GeoDistance[x, y]], {x ∈ CountryData["UnitedStates", "Polygon"], 
  y ∈ CountryData["UnitedStates", "Polygon"]}]
```

It will give a promp that we cannot set a constraint for `x` and `y` by `∈` here.

#### Failure two

```
region = TransformedRegion[
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    CountryData["UnitedStates", "Polygon"]], {#2, #1} &];

geoDist = 
   NMaximize[QuantityMagnitude[GeoDistance[x, y]], {x ∈ region, y ∈ region}]
```

It will give some error informations and a result:

> `{3892.01, {x -> {46.3815, -122.129}, y -> {42.9557, -72.4605}}}`

But after I visualize the results, I don't think it is right:

```
GeoGraphics[{Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
  Arrow@GeoPath[GeoPosition /@ Values[Last[geoDist]]], Red, 
  PointSize[Large], Point[GeoPosition /@ Values[Last[geoDist]]]}]
```

[image]

Those places point by red arrow should have larger distance obviously. And we will also fail to calculate the `TravelDistance` by this method.

```
travelDist = 
 NMaximize[
  QuantityMagnitude[TravelDistance[{GeoPosition[x], GeoPosition[y]}]], 
  {x ∈ region, y ∈ region}]
```

[image]
Actually this error information same to the above expression `...QuantityMagnitude[GeoDistance[x, y]]...`.So any workarounds can calculate `GeoDistance` and `TravelDistance`?

Comment: How does the last example fail? What errors do you get in your attempts?

Comment: @MarcoB Same to the last second example..I should post [these error information](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2017-03-04-23-39-31.png)?

Comment: Yes you should. For instance, in your errors it seems that the calls to `TravelDistance` fail, even before passing a result to `QuantityMagnitude`. That's a good starting point to debug your code: you want to make sure that you can get the calls to `TravelDistance` to work consistently first. Besides, if travel distance requires an external connection, wouldn't the minimization be horribly slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't transform the region, transform the arguments to [`GeoDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDistance.html) instead. Also, account for the possibility that [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) might feed [`GeoDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDistance.html) invalid arguments:

```
gd[x:{__Real}, y:{__Real}] := Quiet @ Check[
    QuantityMagnitude @ GeoDistance[Reverse@x, Reverse@y],
    0
]
```

Then, your basic code works:

```
region = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[CountryData["UnitedStates","Polygon"]];

geoDist = NMaximize[gd[x,y], {x\[Element]region,y\[Element]region}]
```

> {2872.96, {x -> {-124.732, 48.381}, y -> {-80.3997, 25.2389}}}

```
GeoGraphics[{
    Entity["Country","UnitedStates"],
    Arrow @ GeoPath[GeoPosition/@Reverse/@Values[Last[geoDist]]],
    Red, PointSize[Large],
    Point /@ GeoPosition /@ Reverse /@ Values[Last[geoDist]]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: How about `TravelDistance`?I cannot success to do it by your method.

Comment: TravelDistance is a service (so it will be slow) and it is not defined for all geopositions in the US. This makes it hard to use in NMaximize.